# GWT set the visibility of Widget using CSS visibility property

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have a GWT `Button` which contains the `setVisible` function.  The `setVisible` causes the button, or any widget, to disappear by setting its style to `display: none` via a "hidden" class included in the default styles.

```
myButton.setVisible(false); //Just sets style="display: none"
```

I need a clean method that would instead set `visibility: hidden`.  This is easily accomplished by setting the style attribute.

```
myButton.getElement().setAttribute("style", "visibility: "+((isVisible) ? "visible" : "hidden");
```

The problem with doing it this way is that it overrides the current style (not set by the class of course).  Does anybody know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
myButton.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(isVisible);
```

In general, if you want to change only one style, use `.getElement().getStyle()` instead of setting a style attribute.